# C# How to cast a generic delegate type to object and back again

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I have a situation where a System.Dynamic container has to store a type in a dictionary of string to object.  The type stored is a generic delegate.  I need to reconstitute the type in order to call the delegate.

I know based upon the key that the object stored is a known generic delegate type.  I can't figure out how to build an invoke for it.   In VS debugger, looking at the object type the specialization type is known (via Reflection) and the generic delegate type is known.

UPDATE:

```
public delegate void MessageHandlerFunction<in T>(IMessage<T> msg, MessageReceivedInfo info);
```

where the T is an implementation of interface

```
public interface ISpecificMessage
{
    string SiteName { get; set; }
    DateTime MessageTimeStamp { get; set; }
    long MessageNumber { get; set; }
    Guid? PersonId { get; set; }
    DateTime? CreateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    DateTime? ModifyTimeStamp { get; set; }
    int? CreateTimeStampTz { get; set; }
    int? ModifyTimeStampTz { get; set; }
    int? CreateUserId { get; set; }
    int? ModifyUserId { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, object> Payload { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class SpecificMsg1 : SpecificMessage
{
}

[Serializable]
public class SpecificMsg2 : SpecificMessage
{
}
```

Each concrete delegate

```
    private void ProcessSpecificMsg1( IMessage<SpecificMsg1> msg, MessageReceivedInfo info )
    {
        _logger.InfoWrite("received message: SpecificMsg1 from siteName: {0}", msg.Body.SiteName);
    }
```

etc.

I have to store the delegate function in a Dictionary

Later, while running within a System.Threading.Task  I need to reconstiture the delegate and call it.

```
var context = new Dictionary<string,object>();
context["MessageHandlerFunction"] = ProcessSpecificMsg1;
context["Msg"] = msg;
context["Info"] = info;

public class Runner
{
    public void Run( Dictionary<string,object> ctx )
    {
        var mhf = ctx["MessageHandlerFunction"];
        MessageReceiveInfo info = ctx["Info"] as MessageReceiveInfo;
        var msg = ctx["Msg"];

        //  mhf is an object type but was a delegate to a specific specialization of generic delegate.

        // How to cast to correct delegate type and call it at runtime via reflection is the question.

        ((MessageHandlerFunction<>)mhf)(msg,info);
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you provided some code, including what exactly you're trying to do with a `// ???` at the part you're not sure about.

Comment: With the code I can now follow what you're setting up, but I don't know why it's failing.  Please add an example of your `Dictionary` and the `Invoke()` call you'd *like* to make.

Comment: Hmm... I think your best answer is going to be to replace the dictionary with a custom object that stores all those properties.  Is that feasible?

Comment: I tried that in a previous attempt.   Couldn't figure out how to store the generic delegate in a container object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = msg as SpecificMsg1;

if (message != null)
{
   // do stuff..
}
```

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear but there are approx 30 specializations of which each has a different process function.   The delegate stored in the collection as object is a function pointer to the appropriate process function.   The problem is to take an object who's type is object but with apriori knowledge is a generic delegate to a specific process function.